# I get an Error when I try to redirect my PHP form to another page after the fields has been received

Tags: php, forms, redirect

I get an Error when I try to redirect my PHP form to another page after the fields has been received.

I created a form, and validated the inputs. Now i want to redirect the user to the home page, when the click on the submit button.

I first checked if there's error on the input and if there's no error, the user should be redirected to the home. I don't know what i did wrong but i got this Error after i clicked on the submit button.

The error message:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.11 Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80
```

This is my code:

```
<?php



$email = $title = $ingredients = '';

$error = [];


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){



// check for email
if(empty($_POST['email'])){
  $error['email'] = ' Email is empty';
} else {
  $email =  $_POST['email'];
  if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $error['email'] = ' Email must contain @ and .';
  }
}

// check for title
if(empty($_POST['title'])){
  $error['title'] = ' Title is empty';
}  else {
  $title =  $_POST['title'];
  if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/', $title)){
    $error['title'] = 'Title must be letters and spaces';
  }

}

// check for ingredients
if(empty($_POST['ingredients'])){
  $error['ingredients'] = ' Ingredients is empty';
}  else {
  $ingredients =  $_POST['ingredients'];
  if(!preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z\s]+)(,\s*[a-zA-Z\s]*)*$/', $ingredients)){
    $error['ingredients'] = 'Ingreients can only contain letters and comma seperated';
  }
}

if(array_filter($error)){

} else {
  die(header('Location : index.php'));
}

}



function xss_safe($value){
return htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <?php include 'template/header.php'?>
  

  <form action="form.php" method="POST">

  <div class="input_div">
  <label >Email :</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" value="<?= xss_safe($email) ?>">
  <?= isset($error['email']) ? '<div class="error_msg">'.$error['email'].'</div>' : '' ?>
  
  <div class="input_div" >
  <label >Pizza Title :</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" value="<?= xss_safe($title) ?>" >
    <?= isset($error['title']) ? '<div class="error_msg">'.$error['title'].'</div>' : '' ?>
  
  <div class="input_div" >
  <label >Ingredients (comma seperated) :</label>
    <input type="text" name="ingredients" value="<?= xss_safe($ingredients) ?>">
    <?= isset($error['ingredients']) ? '<div class="error_msg">'.$error['ingredients'].'</div>' : '' ?>
  
  
  <div class="input_div" >
  <input type="submit" class="submitBtn" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
  
  </form>


  <?= include 'template/footer.php' ?>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try to redirect to the not exiting page at

```
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
```

Check if your file name is **form.php** and you call the form from **/form.php**

Check the screenshot: http://joxi.net/8AnKGpqIyje8Vr